# How to retrieve errors from sfdx force:data:bulk:status

Tags: salesforcedx

When executing an `sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert` command is there a way for retrieving the "=== **Upsert errors**" that appear when using the `-w` flag through the `sfdx force:data:bulk:status` command or any other way?

Comment: Yeah, I'm having trouble getting the errors to display myself.

Comment: force:data:bulk:status seems quite limited. BTW I discovered the force:data:bulk:status -b option to look at batches only works if you use 18-char ids